# Why does Mockito skip tests when I use a large array?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5, junit-jupiter

I have the following test which I am trying to run through Mockito(in a Spring Boot Project):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    void arrayTest() {
        int arrSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[arrSize];

        for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index += 1000) {
            for (int j = index; j < Math.min(index + 1000, arr.length); j++) {
                arr[j] = 500;
            }
        }

        Assertions.assertEquals(arrSize, arr.length);
    }
}
```

Pretty simple test just takes an array and sets its values to an integer number.

But when I run this test though **IntelliJ** I get the following output in the GUI:

[image]

When I change `arrSize` to lets say `10`. The test works as its suppose to.

What is going on here ?

Why is Mockito skipping the test ? **It should give me an OOM error correct ? Not skip the test.**

Is anyone else getting the same behaviour with a similar test ?

Thanks

It seems to be an OOM issue looking at the verbose logs:

[image]

The problem still happens with different objects:

```
@Test
    void arrayTest() {
        int arrSize = 1_00_00_000;
        Map[] arr = new Map[arrSize];

        for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index += 1000) {
            for (int j = index; j < Math.min(index + 1000, arr.length); j++) {
                arr[j] = new HashMap();
            }
        }
        Assertions.assertEquals(arrSize, arr.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Send console output of `arrayTest()`.
I think that it's because you use Integer.MAX_VALUE and it has value **2147483647**. So last value in-work is **2147483000** and next **2147484000** is already out of int type size. So *index* variable just cannot be assigned to this value.

So

- Do not use iteration step 1000, any value in iteration shouldn't be greater then Integer.MAX_VALUE.
- Use any other max value less or equals **2147483000**

Edit after adding OutOfMemoryException trace in the question:

You have no RAM memory resources to allocate array of this size. 2147483647 * 4 bytes = 8.6 GB RAM memory

Comment: That still doesn't explain why its skipping the test right ? It should give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` correct ?

Comment: No, I thing issie should happen on increment.

Comment: By the way, just figured it now. Why you do not use @SpringBootTest annotation on class? It is the way to add tests in spring boot

Comment: And you don't nned to have this mockito extention. You can use mickito in test just with static import

Comment: its a OOM error. It seems Junit interprets OOM as skipping the `@Test`. Edited the question.

Comment: the problem still occurs when I use a value much lower than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: So you have no RAM memory resources to allocate array of this size. 
2147483647 * 4 bytes = 8.6 GB RAM memory. I will add it to the answer